# I want to calculate total number of iterations a code will take

Tags: java, c

This is my code for a simple selection sort.usually the complexity (time) for a sort is number of iterations it has taken for sorting O(n^2) in case of selection sort
When I dry ran this code against sample string of 98765, it gave me 25 iterations.
Just to cross check with my dry ran output i put 2 vbl- noi and noj in my code.

Q: will the number of total iterations be = noi*noj or noi+noj;

```
int index = 0; int noi = 0, noj = 0;

for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
{
    noj++;
    index = j;
    for (i = j; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (a[index] > a[i])
        {
            a[index] = a[index] + a[i];
            a[i] = a[index] - a[i];
            a[index] = a[index] - a[i];
            noi++;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Total number of iterations will be NOI, that's it... But you are doing it wrong for worst case time complexity you should put NOI after/before the if condition block

Comment: It´s not like we are here to do otheres Homework...

Comment: Shift66's answer is correct

Comment: @KevinEsche   I was asking a doubt and not for someone to do it for me. Chill!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

number of iterations is always 15 (5+4+3+2+1) because in your loops there are `j<5` and `i<5`.  So your code complexity is O(n^0) because in your case n is 5

Comment: its not always 25 as second loop starts from j not 0

Comment: the complexity is not O(n^0) aswell ;)

Answer (score 2):

Complexity doesn't depend from `n` because there's no `n`. The complexity is always exactly 15 (1+2+3+4+5 as said shift66)

Answer (score 0):

it is:  noj [for first loop]    +    (( noj * (noj + 1) ) / 2) [for inner loop]

as first loops is from 1-noj and second is j-noj (where j depends on first loop)